# Using su with commands

Tags: linux, bash, git, su

*Ubuntu Server 12.04*

On a remote server that I ssh into I have set up a special user with:

`sudo adduser --system --disabled-login --disabled-password --group suser`

to run some maintenance functions.  On occasions I su into a login session for `suser` with:

`sudo su -l suser -s /bin/bash`

to do some tasks... however I particularly want to be able to run some git commands via:

`sudo su suser -c <COMMAND>`

from my real user and no login to the suser.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to determine **HOW** I go about that.  I have tried the only ways that makes sense to me:

```
sudo su suser -c git clone https://example.com/repos/project.git
sudo su suser -c "git clone https://example.com/repos/project.git"
   or even
sudo su suser -c mkdir /home/suser/test
sudo su suser -c "mkdir /home/suser/test"
```

but nothing happens and I return to prompt.  Can anyone assist or explain why this isn't possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `suser` was created with `/bin/false` as its default shell. Therefore, when you try to run commands as `suser` through `sudo`, the system attempts to run them using `/bin/false/` which is not a real shell and fails. You can either set a shell for `suser` or you can specify it on the command line when you run `sudo`. Alternatively, you can use `sudo`'s `-u` option.

1. Use `-u`:

   ```
   sudo -u suser mkdir /home/suser/foo
   ```

   This works because by default, `sudo` uses `/bin/bash` (or whatever you have set the default `$SHELL` to be). Therefore, it will execute a command as `suser` but using `bash`, so the command is correctly executed.
2. Set `suser`'s default shell:

   ```
   sudo chsh suser
   ```

   Enter `/bin/bash` (or whatever you prefer) in the prompt that will appear. You should now be able to launch commands as `suser`:

   ```
   sudo su suser -c "mkdir /home/suser/test"
   ```
3. Set the shell explicitly:

   ```
   sudo su suser -s /bin/bash -c "mkdir /home/suser/test"
   ```

Comment: That's it... *facepalm*  I was under the mistaken impression that since I wasn't doing `-l`, that I was keeping the current shell and environment.  Thank you!